# Convert int in to nice time format?

Tags: c#, timer

I have a int that stores how many seconds I have left on a timer, what I want to do is convert that to a nice time format, so for example

If the timer was 604:

```
"10 minutes and 4 seconds"
```

If the timer was 2942

```
"49 minutes and 2 seconds"
```

If the timer was 61

```
"1 minute and 1 second"
```

Is there a simple way to do this other than running lots of if checks to convert it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NuGet package [Humanizer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Humanizer) is designed to create human readable strings for dates, times etc. In particular it can convert a `TimeSpan` into a humanized string.

Adding `using Humanizer;` to the top of your source file will add an extension method to `TimeSpan` that will return intervals exactly as you desire. E.g.

```
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(604).Humanize(precision: 2, collectionSeparator: " and ")
```

will return

```
10 minutes and 4 seconds
```

Humanizer handles pluralization (of course):

```
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(61).Humanize(precision: 2, collectionSeparator: " and ")
```

returns

```
1 minute and 1 second
```

Humanizer allows you to tweak the formatting in many ways and the package also supports multiple languages.

Answer (score 3):

```
TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(604);
string nicelyFormatted = string.Format("{0:D2} minutes and {1:D2} seconds and {2:D3} miliseconds",
    t.Minutes,
    t.Seconds,
    t.Milliseconds);
```

I included the miliseconds as well if you need it. The `D2` means 2 digits so you can put whatever you prefer.

Comment: But this will always include minutes, seconds and ms, I want it only to show what is needed so if seconds < 60 then its 0 minutes, so just show seconds and ms.

Comment: @Ashkru write an if statement: `if (number <= 60) { nicelyFormatted = string.Format("{0:D2} seconds and {1:D3} miliseconds", t.Seconds, t.Milliseconds);}`

Comment: Ignoring the milliseconds then for 61 seconds the resulting string will be `1 minutes and 1 seconds`. However, the desired result is `1 minute and 1 second` (no pluralization).

Comment: @martinliversage yes you are right. I guess the OP can adjust it as needed for the different cases.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a simple way to do this other than running lots of if checks to convert it to?

No, unfortunately, you will have to code.

But I think the code below will meet your need.

```
public static void TimeFormat(StringBuilder format, string name, ref int delta, int time)
{
    if (delta >= time)
    {
        if (format.Length > 0)
            format.Append(" and ");

        format.Append(delta / time).Append(" ").Append(name).Append((delta >= time * 2 ? "s" : ""));
        delta %= time;
    }
}

public static string NiceTimeFormat(int seconds)
{
    StringBuilder format = new StringBuilder();

    const int second = 1;
    const int minute = 60 * second;
    const int hour = 60 * minute;
    const int day = 24 * hour;
    const int month = 30 * day;
    const int year = 365 * day;

    int delta = seconds;

    TimeFormat(format, "year", ref delta, year);
    TimeFormat(format, "month", ref delta, month);
    TimeFormat(format, "day", ref delta, day);
    TimeFormat(format, "hour", ref delta, hour);
    TimeFormat(format, "minute", ref delta, minute);
    TimeFormat(format, "second", ref delta, second);

    return format.ToString();
}
```

To use it:

```
NiceTimeFormat(604);
NiceTimeFormat(2942);
NiceTimeFormat(61);
```